# Read csv with pandas with commented header

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have CSV files that have `#` in the header line:

```
s = '#one two three\n1 2 3'
```

If I use `pd.read_csv` the `#` sign gets into the first header:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True)
     #one  two  three
0     1    2      3
```

If I set the argument `comment='#'`, then `pandas` ignores the line completely.

Is there an easy way to handle this case?

Second issue, related, is how can I handle quoting in this case, it works with no `#`:

```
s = '"one one" two three\n1 2 3'
print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True))
   one one  two  three
0        1    2      3
```

it doesn't with `#`:

```
s = '#"one one" two three\n1 2 3'
print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True))
   #"one  one"  two  three
0      1     2    3    NaN
```

Thanks!

**++++++++++ Update**

here is a test for the second example.

```
s = '#"one one" two three\n1 2 3'
# here I am cheating slicing the string
wanted_result = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s[1:]), delim_whitespace=True)
# is there a way to achieve the same result configuring somehow read_csv?
assert wanted_result.equals(pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True))
```

Comment: Can't you just rename the errant column name for both cases? it seems like you're abusing the `comment` param when it's designed for ignoring comment lines specifically, in the second case I'd just rename it, not a big deal

Comment: In the second case I cannot rename, I have 2 columns, one named `#"one` and the second named `one"`.

Comment: This is not an "errant column". This is a quite common situation which pandas fails to properly deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the first header of the `read_csv()` output this way:

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True)
new_name =  df.columns[0].split("#")[0]
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:new_name})
```

Comment: thanks this works for the first case, any suggestion on the second case? there I get an extra `NaN` column

Comment: you want to rename/remove the `NaN` columns?

Comment: no, in the second case I get 4 columns, the first named `#"one` and the second `one"`. renaming won't work.

Comment: @AndreaZonca sorry that makes no sense you have 3 values but 4 columns, this implies a `NaN` value

Comment: I want 3 columns, not 4, pandas does not do quoting right because of the `#`. check my last 2 examples.

Comment: can you give us an example of the second case? And if it's possible a generalization of the problem? thanks

Comment: the example of the second case is at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the first # of your file this way :

```
s = u'#"one one" two three\n1 2 3'

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

wholefile=StringIO(s).read().split("#")[1]

pd.read_csv(StringIO(wholefile), delim_whitespace=True)

   one one  two  three
0        1    2      3
```

The inconvenient is that you need to load the whole file in memory, but it works.