# Skip rows stated with "#" using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a large data-set like this:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##fileDate=20201231
##source=PLINKv1.90
##contig=<ID=1,length=188260454>
##contig=<ID=10,length=85155382>
##contig=<ID=11,length=61676533>
##contig=<ID=12,length=36989714>
##contig=<ID=13,length=43784426>
##contig=<ID=14,length=94600040>
##contig=<ID=15,length=92851205>
##contig=<ID=16,length=88959756>
##contig=<ID=17,length=80722365>
##contig=<ID=18,length=82634671>
##contig=<ID=19,length=62678559>
##contig=<ID=2,length=121349915>
##contig=<ID=20,length=65336538>
##contig=<ID=3,length=121351672>
##contig=<ID=4,length=109462228>
##contig=<ID=5,length=96758658>
##contig=<ID=6,length=87227659>
##contig=<ID=7,length=100781181>
##contig=<ID=8,length=97562725>
##contig=<ID=9,length=85788908>
##contig=<ID=21,length=58983846>
##contig=<ID=22,length=50925167>
##contig=<ID=23,length=55555792>
##contig=<ID=24,length=48279991>
##contig=<ID=25,length=40282582>
##contig=<ID=26,length=43147527>
##contig=<ID=27,length=40254630>
##contig=<ID=28,length=47348126>
##contig=<ID=29,length=34775913>
##contig=<ID=30,length=31395421>
##contig=<ID=31,length=26000291>
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  A1  A2  A3  A4
1   235 1   A   C   .   .   PR  GT  1|1 1|1 0|0 0|1
1   1000    2   G   C   .   .   PR  GT  1|1 0|1 0|1 1|1
1   1256    3   T   G   .   .   PR  GT  1|1 1|1 0|1 1|1
1   5000    4   T   A   .   .   PR  GT  0|1 0|0 0|1 1|1
1   6234    5   A   T   .   .   PR  GT  0|1 1|1 1|0 0|1
1   77453   6   A   C   .   .   PR  GT  1|0 1|0 1|0 1|0
1   84004   7   C   G   .   .   PR  GT  0|1 1|0 0|1 0|0
1   123658  8   A   T   .   .   PR  GT  1|1 0|0 1|1 0|0
1   432567  9   T   A   .   .   PR  GT  0|1 1|1 0|0 0|0
1   567432  10  A   G   .   .   PR  GT  0|0 1|1 0|1 1|1
1   1234542 11  C   A   .   .   PR  GT  0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
```

To read this data farame I must use this command:

```
snp = pd.read_csv("Imputed.vcf",delimiter=r"\s+",header=0,skiprows=35)
```

Actually, I want to skip hashtagged rows (rows contain "#"), without counting these rows. is there any way for this case?

Comment: You can filter them out from the dataframe after importing. Post the sample of your dataframe

Comment: Here, I attached an example. As I mentioned this data frame is an example and the real data frame is too large. Therefore, I think filtering after importing is not a suitable way due to the large size of my data frame.

Comment: @jesrael gave you a perfect answer below

Comment: Looks like there was a bug in old versions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366797/pandas-read-csv-how-to-skip-comment-lines

Comment: There's also [python - Read csv with pandas with commented header - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311776/read-csv-with-pandas-with-commented-header), which might be useful in this case (header is commented out with single `#`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If need remove all rows starting by `#` use `comment='#'`:

```
snp = pd.read_csv("Imputed.vcf", sep=r"\s+",comment='#', header=None)
```

If need comment with 2 or more characters it is not now supported.

Possible idea is preprocessing:

```
import csv

#preprocessing
def get_row():
    skipped = []
    with open('Imputed.vcf', 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if row[0].strip()[:2] == '##':
                skipped.append(i)
    return skipped 
                

skip = get_row()
print (skip)

snp = pd.read_csv("Imputed.vcf", sep=r"\s+",skiprows=skip)
```

Comment: Is there any way to skip rows contain two #?

Comment: @Siavash - It is more complicated, because by default pandas escape only string with length 1, need more times for solution.

Comment: @Siavash - Unfortunately not so easy, I add solution for get indices of rows with `##` and pased to `skiprows` parameter.

Comment: Thank you @jesrael. Actually, I used a script the same as your solvation, but as I mentioned I have a large dataset and the "open" function takes a large memory due to the large size of my data set.

Comment: @Siavash - So problem of solution with `snp = pd.read_csv("Imputed.vcf",delimiter=r"\s+",header=0,skiprows=35)` is there is not same number of rows with `##` before header?

Comment: @jesrael. No, for ## the skip rows should be 34

Comment: ya, so `snp = pd.read_csv("Imputed.vcf",delimiter=r"\s+",header=0,skiprows=34)` working well?

Comment: @jesrael yes it works using the chunk procedure

Comment: @Siavash - working, but slow? Because some parameter for skipping `##` is not possible use in `pd.read_csv` now, unfortunately.

Comment: @jesrael Yes, I am trying to use dask or chunk for reading it. Thanks!

Comment: @jesrael is this a bug in pandas?

Comment: @jesrael In Github some people had mentioned this problem:https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21725

Comment: @Siavash - Or https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13948